# Zimbra emails from Postfix queue to eml format

Tags: queue, converters, postfix-mta, zimbra, eml

I'm trying to recover some emails from Zimbra Postfix not delivered ‘deferred’ queue by converting them to eml format.

First it came up that all files from the queue are some kind of binaries which can be viewed somehow by `less` command but that kind of display is not clear to process again for a delivery.

Are there any converters for that kind of messages or some specifications to which I can develop own converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have solved my issue. It came up that Zimbra is using slightly modified Postfix. In that case I was able to convert queued messages using command below (Postfix 2.7+)

`postcat -bh file_name_from_queue > file_name.eml`

or

`postcat -qbh queue_id > file_name.eml`